# ¿Cómo obtener un parámetro de URL intacto? c#

Tags: c#, url, webforms

Tengo el siguiente caso, estoy consumiendo un parámetro pasado por URL mediante un `Request.QueryString`, este parámetro es un string encriptado el cual lo necesito obtener tal cual para poder desencriptarlo, pero el problema es que al consumirlo, los signos (+) desaparecen y me devuelve un espacio en blanco, ¿Cómo puedo evitar esto y que obtenga el parámetro intacto?
Ya intenté con: `Replace`, `Convert.ToString` y `Request`

```
string parametro    = Request.QueryString["valorParametro"];
```

Parámetro original:

> QAbjRuTB+bx9U/Tyjppr1D9GdH1Dz1uuJ25b12qBjbYVs0Qh6gD8iOh++a3KqlIshNDm6LdazKXN9g+Erd5rUvFPJTlqR9kkbePKIk21leb62oViGEYdzQUqI4HH1CEP

Parámetro que obtengo:

> QAbjRuTB bx9U/Tyjppr1D9GdH1Dz1uuJ25b12qBjbYVs0Qh6gD8iOh  a3KqlIshNDm6LdazKXN9g Erd5rUvFPJTlqR9kkbePKIk21leb62oViGEYdzQUqI4HH1CEP

Parámetro con HttpUtility.UrlEncode

> QAbjRuTB+bx9U%2fTyjppr1D9GdH1Dz1uuJ25b12qBjbYVs0Qh6gD8iOh++a3KqlIshNDm6LdazKXN9g+Erd5rUvFPJTlqR9kkbePKIk21leb62oViGEYdzQUqI4HH1CEP

Comment: Hola Jorge Luis, como comentario, no creo que necesites codificar los espacios ya que en realidad la variable que se envió vía el querystring  inicialmente seguramente contenía espacios; de otra forma si en realidad requieres los "+"  puedes codificar la variable mediante HttpUtility.UrlEncode() o Server.UrlEncode()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad el parámetro que obtienes es correcto, los signos "+" indican espacios, esto para ser representados en un QueryString.

Si deseas tener los "+" puedes codificar la variable mediante `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`:

```
string parametro = Request.QueryString["valorParametro"];
parametro = HttpUtility.UrlEncode( parametro );
```

o mediante `Server.UrlEncode()`:

```
string parametro = Request.QueryString["valorParametro"];
parametro = Server.UrlEncode( parametro );
```

---

Al realizar lo anterior existe un problema, los caracteres como "/" cambian a su representación hexadecimal por ejemplo "/" a "%2f", si se desea únicamente obtener los "+", lo recomendable aquí sería simplemente reemplazar los espacios:

```
string parametro = Request.QueryString["valorParametro"];
parametro = parametro.Replace(" ", "+")
```

para obtener:

> QAbjRuTB+bx9U/Tyjppr1D9GdH1Dz1uuJ25b12qBjbYVs0Qh6gD8iOh++a3KqlIshNDm6LdazKXN9g+Erd5rUvFPJTlqR9kkbePKIk21leb62oViGEYdzQUqI4HH1CEP

Comment: @JorgeLuisAlcantara Debes codificar lo que obtienes no lo que recibes ya que esta códificando los "+" y los convierte a "%2b"

Comment: Si, disculpa edite mi pregunta para mostrar como se ve, lo que cambia es el "/" y se vuelve %2f. No entiendo bien la parte de obtener y recibir, no es lo mismo? Cómo lo podría codificar?

Comment: Estoy reemplazando con Replace("%2f", "/") y ahora si puedo desencriptarlo bien, pero me queda la sensación de que es una mala idea.

Comment: La variable original que se genera en el código en realidad debe tener los espacios, si se usa la codificación todos los caracteres especiales cambian a su representación hexadecimal , por ejemplo "/" a %2f me parece que en este caso sería tratar únicamente los espacios, solo reemplazar los espacios no utilizando codificación, agrego una actualización.

Answer (score 3):

el problema es que el signo `+` se representa como espacio en blanco

deberias hacer un encode de la url

```
string parametro = Server.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["valorParametro"]);
```

saludos